# What can I do with the disassembled weapons shipment?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I found the disassembled weapons shipment near some Fiends and it's valued at almost 5000. The problem is I can't sell it anywhere (it just doesn't show up in the list of items). What am I supposed to do with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an objective of the quest [How Little We Know](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/How_Little_We_Know).